# How does the browser know how to use cachebusting?

Tags: css, caching, browser

If I include a version number or timestamp with my css file how does the browser load the correct version? Why doesn;t it get confused by the ?v=1 inside the quotes?

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser doesn't care what the URL looks like, it just requests the resource from the server.

The server ignores the query string that is sent along in the URL. It is parsed, but for plain data files the query string isn't used for anything, the server just returns the file.

The reason that you get the correct version of the CSS file is that the query string changes the URL, so the browser doesn't use any previous version of the CSS that might be in the cache. Thus it has to request the file from the server.

Comment: Is there a name for this?

Comment: @Anthony_Z: I don't know of any other name than cachebusting. There is no other practical use for adding a querystring that is ignored.

Comment: @Guffa so, cache is maintained on the server side and cache busting happens on the server side?

Comment: @divine: No, the cache is in the browser and the cache busting happens in the browser. Changing the URL prevents the browser from using the file in the cache, because the browser can't know if the server might return a different result for the new URL. The server will actually return a different result, but not because of the added query string, but because the file has changed on the server.

Comment: @Guffa i already know this part
`The reason that you get the correct version of the CSS file is that the query string changes the URL, so the browser doesn't use any previous version of the CSS that might be in the cache. Thus it has to request the file from the server.`

Comment: @Guffa what i dont understand is this `The browser doesn't care what the URL looks like, it just requests the resource from the server.

The server ignores the query string that is sent along in the URL. It is parsed, but for plain data files the query string isn't used for anything, the server just returns the file.`

what do you mean by `browser doesn't care`?. obviously it cares , as the browser has to compare the URL that is invoked at the moment with its BrowserCache